# Orthogonal Inner Product Proof

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

> Let $v$ and $w$ be elements of an inner product space. Prove that $\|v +
>  w\|^2 = \|v\|^2 + \|w\|^2$ iff $v,w$ are orthogonal.

I know that if $v,w$ are orthogonal they are linearly independent. 
Now if I suppose $v_1 + ...+ v_k = 0$ and $w_1 + ... +w_k = 0$

I have that:

$$0 = \langle v_1 + ... + v_k, v_i\rangle = \langle v_1,v_i\rangle + ... + \langle v_k,v_i\rangle = \langle v_i,v_i\rangle = \|v_i\|^2$$

and this is where I am stuck because it doesn't complete the proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using it wrong. You don't care about linear independence, because there are linearly independent vectors which are *not* orthogonal. So it's not enough to use that.

Instead we can use the orthogonality directly, recall that $\|u\|^2=\langle u,u\rangle$, and now we have:
$$\langle v+w,v+w\rangle = \langle v,v\rangle+\langle v,w\rangle+\langle w,v\rangle+\langle w,w\rangle$$

The assumption of orthogonality means that $\langle v,w\rangle =0$, and the conclusions follow.

Comment: Ah, of course! I made it more complicated then it really was. Thank you very much, Asaf!Toda Raba!

Answer (score 3):

Use the fact that $ <u,v>=0 $, and notice that

$$||u+v||^2 =<u+v,u+v>=<u,u>+<u,v>+<v,u>+<v,v>=\dots$$

Comment: Of course, thank you very much, Mhenni!

Comment: @diimension: You are welcome.