# Prove that $u\cdot v = 1/4||u+v||^2 - 1/4||u-v||^2$ for all vectors $u$ and $v$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry

I need some help figuring out how to work through this problem.

> Prove that $ u \cdot v  = 1/4 ||u + v||^2 - 1/4||u - v||^2$ for all vectors $u$ and $v$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Sorry, forgot to include my work so far:

I decided to ignore the 1/4 and deal with it later once I had a better understanding of the question.

$= ||u+v||^2 - ||u-v||^2$

$= (u+v)(u+v) - (u-v)(u-v)$

$= u(u+v) + v(u+v) - u(u-v) + v(u-v)$

$= uu + uv + uv + vv - uu + uv + uv - vv$

$u \cdot v= 3(uv)$

This is as far as I've gotten, not sure if I'm on the right track or where to go next.

Comment: Did you try anything at all? If you expand the right hand side, this is just a couple lines of algebra.

Comment: What do you already know about the dot product, and what have you tried?

Comment: @T.Bongers Sorry mate, I intended on including what I've gotten so far but my daughter woke up mid-post. Figured I'd ask and get some input while I put her back to sleep :).

Comment: No problem at all. For future reference, the buzzword here is "polarization."

Comment: You need to use some properties of dot product.

Comment: You have just made a minor sign mistake..

$$ - \langle u - v, u - v \rangle = - \langle u, u - v \rangle + \langle v, u - v \rangle = - (u \cdot u - 2u \cdot v + v \cdot v) $$

(notice the + not - in the middle expression) then everything cancels except for the $u \cdot v$ terms.

Comment: @Mattos Woops, thanks for the pointing that out. I've (I think) corrected it and am left with 3(uv).

Comment: @TalenKylon You have $4 u \cdot v$, count up your terms again.

Comment: @Mattos Ah thanks again. Could you instruct how to continue once we are  at this point? u $\cdot v$ = 4uv

Comment: @TalenKylon You don't have $u \cdot v = 4 u \cdot v$. You have 

$$\lvert \lvert u + v \rvert \rvert^{2} + \lvert \lvert u - v \rvert \rvert^{2} = 4 u \cdot v$$

Now just divide both sides by $4$ and you have the result you required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a start

> $$||u+v||^2= \langle u+v, u+v \rangle= \langle u, u \rangle+\dots \,. $$

Do the same with the other and multiply both eqs and by $\frac{1}{4}$ and subtract. See [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217744/orthogonal-inner-product-proof).

**Note:**

> $$\langle u, v\rangle = u.v  \,.  $$

Comment: You might want to use \langle and \rangle for the inner product notation.

Comment: @Mattos: you are right!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Remember $\vec{x} \cdot \vec{x} = \left \| x \right \|^2 $. That should be really helpful, in my mind.

And as @T.Bongers said, when working with identities like this, begin with the harder side. Try to "simplify" it (or make it a big more complex before having things cancel!) into the more basic side.